# API Error Code: 100 Error Message: Some content in this message has been reported as abusive by Facebook users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps, facebook-oauth

Today, out of nowhere, my app has stopped working.

I'm getting this message  and when i click `ok`, he redirect and get a server error.

```
API Error Code: 100
API Error Description: Invalid parameter
Error Message: Some content in this message has been reported as abusive by Facebook users.
```

I use Facebook php sdk.

How to fix this?

Comment: And you are getting this error doing ?

Comment: doing nothing.i dont know where the problem is.

Comment: Sorry, I am a little confused.Could you tell where you click OK on?  On authentication part or when posting some content on Wall or something else?

Comment: i click the 'ok' button of the error message. this error message apear everytime i tried to open the app even if the user is not authenticated also this error  apear. i think this is a bug. i fixed it changing the app namespace.now the app works ok